# Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a Rest controller using Spring 4. I'm also using mongodb as a database, and Tomcat 7 as webserver.
I'm getting this error message when i try to submit any Rest request:

```
    type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.buildRequestAttributes(FrameworkServlet.java:996)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.
```

I'm using those version in my pom.xml

```
<!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- spring-web -->
    <spring-web.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring-web.version>

    <!-- Spring data for MongoDB -->
    <springframework.data-version>1.6.1.RELEASE</springframework.data-version>
```

here is the controller class that'm using :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class UserContoller {

    @Autowired
    UserServices userServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User findUserByUsername(@PathVariable ("username") String username){
        return userServices.findUserByUsername(username);

    }

}
```

would you please help me?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public User  findUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    logger.info("Searcing for user using his username");
    return userServices.findUserByUsername(username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I believe a combination of things resolved this issue:

- Make sure that you have the following two lines in your servlet.xml and in this order(meaning annotation-driven must be listed before the default-servlet-handler)

  ```
  <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

  <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
  </bean>
  ```

*Any equivalent viewResolver bean is fine.

- Make sure this is in your web.xml:

  ```
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  ```
- I see you dont mention what you're GET will produce. For Ex: I have this attribute in my @RequestMapping  `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`
- Finally, I'm not sure why but each time I add a new controller mapping, I need to run the Maven Install lifecycle or it doesn't see the new mapping. This issue i'm still trying to figure out.